# how to finish landing website animation and display website main page using React javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image]I want to end landing Page Animation after 2-3 seconds and Display Main Page . So how do i end that loading Animation and Display it. Is there any way I can call setTimeOut?
[[image: I want to end landing Page Animation after 2-3 seconds and Display Main Page . So how do i end that loading Animation and Display it. Is there any way I can call setTimeOut? ][1]]
export default Loader;

Comment: here is a css code.                                                                                                                    body{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
   

}

.loader{
    transition: all linear 0.3s;
    background: #111;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.loader div{
    background:#fff;
    width: 16px;
    height: 32px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: all 300ms;
    animation: loader 1.2s infinite;
}

Comment: Please see [ask]. Images of code are not acceptable, please [edit] your question to include the code itself.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would like to know why would you want to make the user wait for 2-3 seconds if the page loads completely before? I mean, that's a huge impact in User Experience and I totally don't recommend that. Performance nowadays is a KPI in every business.

Besides that, if you really want to make it, I would make a state in the parent component, where it renders the `Loader` component for those seconds and then switch to `Mainpage` component. You can think this as the same for async requests to a server (that takes 2-3 seconds), how do we imitate that? With the `setTimeout` function, as you mentioned.

So the code would be something like the following, in the parent component:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) // generally when doing http requests this is false initially and when starting the request you set it to true, but this case is a bit different

  useEffect(() => {setTimeout(() => {setLoading(false)}, 2000)}, []) // this will execute the code inside the effect once the component is rendered - same as componentDidMount() in class-based components.

  return loading ? <Loader /> : <MainPage />
```

And that's it.

p.d: Remember that the hooks are used inside the functional component, since you used it above it.
Also, you can just import css as `import "../styles/asd.css"`

Comment: Thank you Agustin for your time. I have tried this way as well. But i was getting error like "To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function. in LoginPage (created by ConnectFunction) in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)". So I used another way and it worked                                  
     useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            props.history.push("/dashboard");
        }, 2000);
        return () => props.history.push("/dashboard");
      }, []);

Comment: Cool! Please mark the answer as correct if suitable